# Swift: Linking Facebook users with existing PFUsers Not Working on Parse Server

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook login/signup into my app to work alongside the standard login/signup with email. I am using Swift and have migrated to Parse Server.

I've followed the Parse iOS guide on Facebook Users. However, with Parse Server, the Facebook integration isn't working normally according to all the tutorials and documentation out there.

**How can I link existing PFUsers with their Facebook accounts when they log in with Facebook in the app?**

I am using the Swift code from this section of the guide (https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-linking) to associate an existing PFUser to a Facebook account (see code below), however, this code is not executing for some unknown reason and therefore is not linking a users existing account they created through the email sign up with their Facebook account which has the same email. **Why is this code not executing?**

**UPDATE**: The `isLinkedWithUser` method requires that the user be logged in. However, when a user is signed out/just downloaded the app, the PFUser.currentUser() is nil because the user is not logged in. Therefore, the `linkUserInBackground` method won't know which `PFUser` to link the Facebook account with. I believe these methods are now useless because they are to link after the fact (after they log in). But I don't want to create two users.
Is there a Cloud Code example or other Swift logic to accomplish this?

I am not sure what the problem is. Appreciate any help!

Source: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users

```
func fbLoginButtonTapped() {
    print("fbLoginButtonTapped")

    let permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, block: {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                print("User logged in through Facebook!")

                // This API doesn't seem to be working with Parse Server
                if !PFFacebookUtils.isLinkedWithUser(user) {
                    PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(user, withReadPermissions: nil, block: {
                        (succeeded: Bool?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            print("Woohoo, the user is linked with Facebook!")
                        } else {
                            print("User is not linked with Facebook.")
                        }
                    })
                }


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
                    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })

            }
        } else {
            print("User cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }           

}
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If so could you update your questions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the FBSDK correctly in your Swift app? You should need to add a few callbacks in your app delegate that handle FBSDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/).

Also, was that app running on parse.com or are you using it for the 1st time on parse-server?

Comment: Yes, i did configure the FBSDK correctly. The app is running on parse-server. In my question update, I mentioned that the `isLinkedWithUser` method requires that the user be logged in. Therefore, the `linkUserInBackground` method won't know which PFUser to link the Facebook account with. However, I am trying to link the Facebook user to the existing PFUser _during_ Facebook login so that there won't be duplicate users (with the same email). Not sure why Parse didn't think about this...

Comment: The problem with emails is that it's unsafe to rely on those to link users together. In order to make sure an email belongs to a certain person the password is required.

What you could do, is
1. acquire the access_token from Facebook
2. get the email from the FBSDK
3. send that to a cloud code function, getting all users with that email"
4. if that user is existing, either do the linking in cloud code, and send back the result, or in the client, after the user gets logged in by email/password.

We didn't implement it as it's a problematic specific to your application

Comment: Thanks. 1) At one point are you referring to get the access_token and email from Facebook? Inside my loginWithFacebook method? 2) What type of Cloud Code function? I never worked with Cloud Code before but my thought is a beforeSave function because that way before it saves a duplicate user, I can link the users. At the same time, I'm not sure if I will be able to link since the user won't be in existence yet since it's in a beforeSave. 3) Why do we need to send the access_token too if we only use the email in the logic?

Comment: 4) "in the client, after the user gets logged in by email/password": The main point is for the user to avoid entering their email/password and then linking. That I know can be done. But what if the user taps the Facebook Login button to login/signup?

Comment: 1) I mentioned getting the email with the client Facebook SDK (refer to the Facebook SDK documentation)
2) That's up to you to decide, beforeSave is too late, that can well be a REST endpoint too.
3) The access token is used to validate the identity of the user against Facebook records. Anything that comes from a client can't be trusted. Even a valid access token could be coupled by an attacker with a target's email.
4) The only way to ensure an email belongs to a user is to match it with it's password...